# Type dispatch based on runtime value

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Suppose we're implementing an interpreter for the bytecode of some stack machine.  Let every element of the stack be a `Word8`, and let the stack be represented by a list:

```
type Stack = [Word8]
```

We'll need opcodes for addition, subtraction, and unary negation.  However, apart from acting on `Word8`s, we might want to treat the top two elements together as a `Word16`, and then the next two as another `Word16`, and then do something to those.  To keep things simple:

```
data DataSize = OneByte | TwoBytes | FourBytes deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data OpCode = ... | Add DataSize | Subtract DataSize | Negate DataSize | ...
            deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

`Add OneByte` performs addition of `Word8`s, `Add TwoBytes` performs addition of `Word16`s, etc.

We'll use some monad to store the state of our computation.  It doesn't really matter what we use, so we'll just represent it with `M` here.  Our function to execute one instruction might be

```
exec :: OpCode -> M ()
```

and ideally we'd like to write

```
exec (Add size) = perform get2 (+) size
exec (Subtract size) = perform get2 (-) size
exec (Negate size) = perform get1 negate size
```

where `perform get2 f size` pops two objects of the given size, applies `f` to them, then pushes the result on the stack.

The question, now, is how close we can come to implementing `perform`.  Intuitively, the type is something like

```
-- Stackable is some class of things we can push and pop.
-- c is any constraint.  In the examples above, it would be num.
-- fn{a} is a type with one free variable a.  Haskell does not allow
-- generalising this way, which is why I'm using the non-existent fn{a}
-- notation.
perform :: (forall a. (Stackable a, c a) => fn{a} -> Proxy a -> M ())
               -> (forall a. c a => fn{a})
               -> Size
               -> M ()
```

For any choice of `fn`, this function is easily implemented:

```
perform act f = go
     where go OneByte = act f (Proxy :: Proxy Word8)
     where go TwoBytes = act f (Proxy :: Proxy Word16)
     where go FourBytes = act f (Proxy :: Proxy Word32)
```

Unfortunately, we can't just say `forall fn` (nor, for that matter, `forall c`).  Here's a solution I came up with to allow a single definition of `perform` in the presence of this.  I've simplified a little to reduce the amount of code, so `M` is `IO` and we assume all values involved support plenty of operations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies, EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Proxy

-- This is the runtime value we'll use to decide what type we're operating on.
data DataSize = DSInt | DSDouble
-- I haven't found a way to support arbitrary constraints, so the solution
-- for now is to throw in a bunch that I know the types involved will support.
type SimpleNum a = (Num a, Eq a, Ord a, Read a, Show a)

-- We use this as a placeholder for a in the types
data Hole

-- This is meant to be something like a lambda on the type level.
-- fn should be a type with some "holes" in it, and Lambda fn a should
-- be isomorphic to the type with the holes filled with a.
data family Lambda fn a

data instance Lambda (Hole -> r) a = LambdaTakingHole { getLambdaTakingHole :: a -> Lambda r a }
data instance Lambda Hole a = LambdaHole { getLambdaHole :: a }
data instance Lambda (IO ()) a = LambdaIO { getLambdaIO :: IO () }

-- This is a helper typeclass to allow uniform conversion to and from
-- values of the form Lambda fn a.  With the recursion going on, this makes
-- wrapping far easier.

class LambdaLike fn where
    -- UnderlyingFun fn a is the type that Lambda fn a should be isomorphic to.
    -- wrapf and unwrapf are the isomorphism.
    type family UnderlyingFun fn a
    wrapf :: UnderlyingFun fn a -> Lambda fn a
    unwrapf :: Lambda fn a -> UnderlyingFun fn a

instance LambdaLike r => LambdaLike (Hole -> r) where
    type UnderlyingFun (Hole -> r) a = a -> UnderlyingFun r a
    wrapf f = LambdaTakingHole (wrapf . f)
    unwrapf (LambdaTakingHole f) = unwrapf . f

instance LambdaLike Hole where
    type UnderlyingFun Hole a = a
    wrapf = LambdaHole
    unwrapf = getLambdaHole

instance LambdaLike (IO ()) where
    type UnderlyingFun (IO ()) a = IO ()
    wrapf = LambdaIO
    unwrapf = getLambdaIO

-- Here are some example functions we could write
-- These are given a specific instantiation of the function they need
-- to work with, and then a proxy to indicate the type involved.

runWith2 :: SimpleNum a => (Lambda (Hole -> IO ()) a) -> Proxy a -> IO ()
runWith2 (unwrapf -> f) _ = f 2

runWithUserInput :: SimpleNum a => (Lambda (Hole -> IO ()) a) -> Proxy a -> IO ()
runWithUserInput (unwrapf -> f) _ = getLine >>= f . read

runWith2andPrint :: SimpleNum a => (Lambda (Hole -> Hole) a) -> Proxy a -> IO ()
runWith2andPrint (unwrapf -> f) _ = print $ f 2

runWith2and5 :: SimpleNum a => (Lambda (Hole -> Hole -> IO ()) a) -> Proxy a -> IO ()
runWith2and5 (unwrapf -> f) _ = f 2 5

perform :: (forall a. SimpleNum a => Lambda fn a -> Proxy a -> IO ())
               -> (forall a. SimpleNum a => Lambda fn a)
               -> DataSize
               -> IO ()
perform fn f = go
    where go DSInt = fn f (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
          go DSDouble = fn f (Proxy :: Proxy Double)

main = do
    perform runWith2 (wrapf print) DSInt
    perform runWith2 (wrapf print) DSDouble
    perform runWith2andPrint (wrapf (+1)) DSInt
    perform runWith2and5 (wrapf $ \x y -> print $ x + y) DSInt
    perform runWith2and5 (wrapf $ \x y -> print $ x * y) DSDouble
```

Is this a good solution to the problem?  Am I reinventing some wheel here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with using Data.Word so I switched to using ints. I think your solution looks to be overkill. How does my solution match your specification?

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Applicative
import Data.List


type Stack = [Int]

data DataSize = OneByte | TwoBytes | FourBytes deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

data OpCode = Add DataSize | Subtract DataSize | Negate DataSize
                        deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

type M = State Stack

exec :: OpCode -> M ()
exec (Add size) = get2 size (+)
exec (Subtract size) = get2 size (-)
exec (Negate size) = get1 size negate

-- 5 + 6 with one byte
test1 :: M ()
test1 = do
  push 5
  push 6
  add OneByte

-- 256 + 1 with two bytes
test2 :: M ()
test2 = do
  push 0
  push 1
  push 1
  push 1
  add TwoBytes

push x = modify (x:)
add = exec . Add
sub = exec . Subtract
neg = exec . Negate

get2 :: DataSize -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> M ()
get2 ds f  = do
  (a, b) <- (,) <$> getArg ds <*> getArg ds
  modify (to8 (f a b) ++)

get1 :: DataSize -> (Int -> Int) -> M ()
get1 ds f = do
  a <- getArg ds
  modify (to8 (f a) ++)

getArg :: DataSize -> M Int
getArg OneByte = takeByte
getArg TwoBytes = to16 <$> takeByte <*> takeByte

to8 :: Integral a => a -> [a]
to8 = unfoldr f

f :: Integral a => (a -> Maybe (a, a))
f bs = case bs == 0 of
            True -> Nothing
            False -> Just $ (rem bs 255, div bs 255)

to16 a b = (255 * a) + b

takeByte :: M Int
takeByte = gets head <* modify tail
```

Comment: Operating on the most general type is an option, and works for integers; could you show how you'd generalise this to floats and doubles, though?

Comment: I was under the impression you were using discrete values? If you mean how would you do it with Word8 etc then I assume you can do similar sorts of things with shifting 8 bits rather than doing div 255.

Comment: Well, the Word8 vs Int thing isn't going to matter much (seeing as you only use the bottom 8 bits, anyway).  However, I don't see how to easily extend your solution to allow adding two doubles, which mine does.

Comment: I never suggested it did but I didn't realise from your specification you wanted it to.